# OCMock does not forward valueForKeyPath: calls

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

I have object A that has a property that returns a mock object. I then ask object A for `valueForKeyPath:` where the path is a path to the mock object's property. I can see in the debugger that `valueForKeyPath:` is correctly executed on object A and that it calls `valueForKey:` on object A which returns the mocked object. However, the mocked object never gets a call to `valueForKeyPath:` or `valueForKey:`.

This is my mock creation:

```
self.reservationMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[Reservation class]];
self.sut = [[Controller alloc] initWithReservation:self.reservationMock];
```

The mock is stored in `reservation`. I evaluate a predicate with `reservation.reservationMode` on the `sut`.

I get the following calls:

- `valueForKeyPath:@"reservation.reservationMode"`
- `valueForKey:@"reservation"`

And that's it. If I do not mock the object, the evaluation continues with the following calls on the `Reservation` object.

- `valueForKeyPath:@"reservationMode"`
- `valueForKey:@"reservationMode"`

Any idea what is going on here?